# Checkable: triggering onClick event without changing its visual state

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-checkbox

does someone know if I can make a Checkable trigger the click event without changing its visual state?

like if it's checked it stays checked but the onClick or some other function is triggered?

if it's possible, would you mind explaining how?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just let it check it self again when it get's unchecked. Something like this: onClick{ if(!isChecked()) view.check() }

Comment: calling setChecked triggers the onCheckedChangeListener so that results in an infinite loop

Comment: Did you try it with the (negated) if statement?